# How to prevent changes of entity relationships?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I am using spring boot for to store complex json-structures via JPA in our database.

The root of the json-structure represents a "House" object. A "House" object contains several "Furnitures". For example:

```
House ID: 4711
|- Furniture: ID 4712 (with confidential information)
```

Users have read/write permissions for certain Houses, and all their "Furnitures".

My problem is, that through the REST-API, the user can "steal" Furnitures from other Houses, if he knows their primary keys; with request like this one:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/house

{
    houseId: 99991337,
    furnitures: [{
        furnitureId: 4712,
        ...
    }]
}
```

This leads to:

```
House ID: 4711
|- empty!

House ID: 99991337
|- Furniture 4712 (with confidential information)
```

Althought the user did not have permission to House 4711, he "unlinked" Furniture 4712 from House 4711 and instead linked it to House 99991337.

How can I prohibit the change of the House of a Furniture?

In the JPA-Entities, there is a bidirectional OneToMany-Relationship from House to Furniture. I thought of maybe searching in the database any Furniture of incoming requests, check all permissions on all of them. But I would prefer to only have to check the permission on the House (because in real life, I have many more entities like Furniture)

Comment: How the permissions to `houses` are defined?

Comment: @htshame I added an example for authorization. In my real application all of this is much more complicated - but I am confident, that a good answer for this reduced example will serve me well for my complex real world application.

Comment: Do you mean furniture with some ID can be used only once?

Comment: @Akceptor Yes, a furniture should *belong to* exactly *one* house and should be privately be owned by that house. Only those users permitted to see/edit the house should be able to see/edit its furniture.

Comment: So, in the existing condition, users can create new furniture every time they create a house with `POST http://localhost:8080/house`?

Comment: @hutabalian Yes, I am using `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "house", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)` in `House` for the relationships to all its `Furniture`. This creates/updates/deletes all Furniture, when saving a house.

Comment: `user can "steal" Furnitures from other Houses, if he knows their primary keys`. But what if user doesn't know them? Perhaps, you can add `house_uuid` to `house` table, and `furniture_uuid` to `furniture` table to replace `houseId` and `furnitureId`, so on the front-end side you'll be able to operate only with uuids, thus hiding the real database ids from the user.

Comment: It sounds like you should map `Furniture` as an @Embeddable instead of an @Entity.

Answer (score 3):

If my understanding is correct, just search the permissions table by `userId` and `houseId` that was provided in the request.
If there is a match, then the user has permissions to change the `houseId`.

Depending on the permissions you can either set or not set `houseId` to the object that you are about to save to the database.

If you still want the user to change the `furniture data` then you can save only `furniture` entity by providing `furnitureId` and `text` for the `new Furniture()` object.

Comment: Thanks, I think this solution would indeed work for me. However I would prefer an out-of-the-box solution, which does not require to query the Furniture-table first (in my real world application I have many different Entity-Classes besides Furniture, all in direct or indirect relations to House). Do you know of any Annotation or similar, that implicitly does this check for me?

Comment: I guess it depends on your security layer implementation. You might want to check out the `@PreAuthorise` annotation in `spring-security`, it might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

First of all your request structure is incorrect. For secure reasons like this you could not ask to user for his userid, houseid etc.. You need to handle it in background without relying to user request.

But for this situation you can simply change the insert statement with a select insert. Join the permission table to select statement to check given id is attached to related user. If nothing inserted user tries to insert illegal id.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to put handler on update of `Furniture` entity table with annotation `@HandleBeforeSave`and `@RepositoryEventHandler` and inside this handler you can query only this `Furniture` entity and check which `House` it belongs. And then decide what to do with this update request

Answer (score 0):

If the following statement holds true:

`Yes, a furniture should belong to exactly one house and should be privately be owned by that house. Only those users permitted to see/edit the house should be able to see/edit its furniture.`

In my mind it means you should not be allowed to create a house with furniture that is already attached to another house (Business requirement).

I would check first if the furniture doesn't belong to another house before creating the house (preserve data integrity) and throw an exception if it does. I see this happening in the business layer, which will cater for any outer boundary call which might compromise the data/requirement.

You could move it outside your business layer, but then the possibility is there that you might duplicate code per channel or miss one/two channels.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - it seems to be a good and clean solution. However, since I have dozens of Entity-classes attached to my `House`, this will cost a lot of code.